# How useful is ionice tool with modern linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, io, ionice

The `ionice` tool is supposed to offer relief on high I/O load by executing commands only when the system is in a specified state.

The [man page](https://www.linux.org/docs/man1/ionice.html) states:

> Linux supports I/O scheduling priorities and classes since 2.6.13 with the CFQ I/O scheduler.

However CFQ I/O has been deprecated and removed from kernel since 5.3.

So what is the state of this utility? Does it actually work at all on modern kernels?

Additional piece of information

- `ionice` uses kernel call `ioprio_set`
- The [documentation](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioprio_set.2.html) states:

  > These system calls have an effect only when used in conjunction with an I/O scheduler that supports I/O priorities.  As at kernel 2.6.17 the only such scheduler is the Completely Fair Queuing (CFQ) I/O scheduler.